# Invalid index error simulating bipolar NRZ on SCILAB

Tags: binary, sequence, simulation, communication, scilab

I'm trying to simulate a bipolar NRZ of [1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1] on SCILAB. But I keep getting error of "invalid index". Need help...

This is the error that I get on SCILAB.

[invalid index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJIwr.png)

This is my source code.
[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDAqW.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple indexing error.

Remember that, in `Scilab`, arrays are indexed starting from `1` (not `0` like `Python` or other languages)

In your code, you are checking a `elseif` condition involving `x(i - 1)` and your `for` loop loops through `1:L`, so, at the first comparison iteration, `x(0)` will be tested, which is undefined/invalid.